# SQL Injection only with OR

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, ctf

I am doing a practise SQL injection in a search field and I don't understand the logic of what is happening.

The following behaviours is what I noticed:

Entering `' OR '1' = '1` shows all the results.

Entering `'` Shows no results (shows 'no results found')

Entering `test` shows some relevant results

Entering `test' AND '1' = '1` shows nothing (not even 'no results found')

Entering `test' OR '1' = '1` shows all the results.

What I don't understand is that it seems the logical OR is working but not the AND. How could this be, any ideas? Any SQL commands I tried don't seem to work (like sleep etc.) and result in nothing (not even 'no results found').

PS: When I tried a more complicated injection with UNION it got blocked by WAF and I bypassed it with /**/ comment blocks in the statements, this is a for a CTF challenge and i'm trying to learn about injection.

EDIT1:

Writing the result queries out makes sense:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` LIKE '%' OR '1' = '1%'";
sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` LIKE '%'%'";
sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` LIKE '%test%'";
sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` LIKE '%test' AND '1' = '1%'";
sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` LIKE '%test' OR '1' = '1%'";
```

EDIT2: I just tried: %’ AND ‘1%’ LiKE ‘1 results to:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` LIKE ‘%%’ AND ‘1%’ LiKE ‘1%'";
```

But it doesn't show results, which means I was not right and the query is probably different :(

EDIT3: Another thing I noticed is that its inside parenthesis:

```
keyword')-- -
```

works but

```
keyword'-- -
```

doesnt, still AND or UNION doesn't seem to work

Comment: From your answer, it sounds like the source of your problem is simply that wildcard matching is being used.  As a result you just need to close not just the single quote but also the wild card, i.e. try `test%' AND '1'='1`

Comment: @ConorMancone See the edit in my answer, I was wrong

Comment: its very strange, but im pretty sure its vulnerable considering the OR works, also I managed to exploit XSS in the same field, but I cant get any further, sqlmap doesnt help either

Comment: Is this something you're running locally and can therefore you can get access to the code itself?

Comment: May I ask is the CTF public? I might want to try it myself.

Comment: No, but after the challenge is over I will ask the code